# File Upload into reactive Form via Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, file-upload, angular-reactive-forms

I followed this tutorial for impementing an file upload into my reactive form:
https://netbasal.com/how-to-implement-file-uploading-in-angular-reactive-forms-89a3fffa1a03
but I'm Having a problem: "this.onChange is not a function"
my Component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'first-page',
  templateUrl: './first-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./first-page.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: FirstPageComponent,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
 @Input()progress;
  onChange:Function;
  private file:File|null=null;

  @HostListener('change',['$event.target.files']) emitFiles(event:FileList){
    const file= event && event.item(0);
    this.onChange(file);
    this.file=file;
  }
  writeValue(value:null){
    //clear file input
    this.host.nativeElement.value='';
    this.file=null;
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: Function){
    this.onChange = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: Function){
  }



  
  ngOnInit(){
  this.profileForm= new FormGroup({
  nomeControl:new FormControl('' , [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(30)]),
  cognomeControl:new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(20)]),
  telefonoControl:new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10), Validators.maxLength(10)]),
  emailControl:new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]),
  capControl:new FormControl('', [Validators.required,  Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(5)]),
  comuneControl:new FormControl('', ),
  provinciaControl:new FormControl({value:'', disabled:true}),
  regioneControl:new FormControl({value:'', disabled:true}),
  indirizzoControl:new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
  codiceFiscaleControl:new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(
    '[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z]+[A-Za-z]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[A-Za-z]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[A-Za-z]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[0-9]+[A-Za-z]$'
    )]),
  });

  this.objectivesForm=new FormGroup({
  obiettiviPersonaliControl:new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
  obiettiviMotivazionaliControl:new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),});

  this.professionalObjForm=new FormGroup({
  obiettiviProfessionaliControl:new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),});

  this.lavoriPassatiForm=new FormGroup({
  positiveExControl:new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
  negativeExControl:new FormControl('',[Validators.required]),
  commentsControl:new FormControl('')})

    this.knowledgeForm=new FormGroup({
    knowledge:new FormControl(''),
    conoscenzeForm:new FormArray([]),});

  this.uploadForm=new FormGroup({
  cvUpload1Control:new FormControl('',[Validators.required, requiredFileType('pdf','doc','docx')]),
  cvUpload2Control:new FormControl('',[Validators.required, requiredFileType('pdf','doc','docx')])});
  }
  onInputChange(event: MatSliderChange){
    this.myValue=event.value;
  }
  public checkErrorP=(controlName:string, errorName:string)=>{
    return this.profileForm.controls[controlName].hasError(errorName);
  }
  public checkErrorO=(controlName:string, errorName:string)=>{
    return this.objectivesForm.controls[controlName].hasError(errorName);
  } 
  public checkErrorPr=(controlName:string, errorName:string)=>{
    return this.professionalObjForm.controls[controlName].hasError(errorName);
  } 
  public checkErrorEx=(controlName:string, errorName:string)=>{
    return this.lavoriPassatiForm.controls[controlName].hasError(errorName);
  } 
  public checkErrorK=(controlName:string, errorName:string)=>{
    return this.knowledgeForm.controls[controlName].hasError(errorName);
  } 
  public checkErrorUp=(controlName:string, errorName:string)=>{
    return this.uploadForm.controls[controlName].hasError(errorName);
  } 
  addSkill(){
    //this.conoscenze.push((<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("knowledge")).value);
    this.knowledgeForm.value.conoscenzeForm.push(new FormControl({name: this.conoscenze[this.i] , value:this.myValue}));
    this.i++;}
```

I'mc just not getting what the error is.
Otherwise can you tell me another solution for a file Upload via reactive form?(my starting idea was to implement the tutorial for 2 file uploads)

Comment: You need to create a separate component (file-upload-component) that contains all the ControlValueAccessor stuff. Look carefully in the linked tutorial code snippets.. in the footers of those snippets it will show you what file is being described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MikeOne was right, i needed to separate component that contains all the controlValueAccessor.